# Is it safe to install the Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: installation, drivers, nvidia, 13.04

In 12.10, the installation of the Nvidia driver was risky and nerve-wrecking.  Fortunately, I was able to find [some instructions](http://falkvinge.net/2013/02/15/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal/) to get it to work, but unfortunately not until after borking an install.

Have the bugs with the Nvidia driver installation in 12.10 been fixed in 13.04?  Is it safe to install the Nvidia driver using [the steps detailed here](http://falkvinge.net/2013/02/15/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal/), or better yet, by just running `apt-get install nvidia-current-updates`?

EDIT:

I do not believe this question is a duplicate, because the one linked to *does not* address the safety of the install, nor the issues that arose in 12.10.  Before asking this question, I found the one you linked to and it did not satisfy my question, thus the reason I asked.

Also, this is no small bug.  It completely destroyed my system and forced a complete reinstall.  After a traumatic experience such as that, a little verification that the bug is fixed is not only prudent, but necessary.

Comment: iirc that was fixed in updated versions of 12.10.

Comment: @JorgeCastro Please read my question closer.  I am not asking how to install drivers.  I am asking if the "normal" steps are safe to use, since they *definitely were not* for Ubuntu 12.10 when it first shipped.

Comment: they are safe to install, I linked to the proper instructions.

Comment: FWIW, I think this question has value to future Googlers like myself who are terrified to follow the "normal" insructions for installing the Nvidia driver.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that "is my favorite bug from the last release fixed?" questions are typically offtopic. We'll just keep an eye out for incoming nvidia questions and if it becomes a big deal perhaps deal with it then.

Comment: (Feel free to write up an answer if you think it'll help)

Comment: I can confirm it's working fine for me on a GTX 670 OC, with the 310 (proprietary, tested) using the Software & Updates > Additional Drivers pane. I wanted to try this because the "apt-get" method pulls the 304.88 drivers. I did however run `sudo nvidia-xconfig` once in Terminal before rebooting, just to be sure.

Comment: I've moved this discussion here as there are multiple nvidia questions about this issue: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6631/which-is-the-canonical-nvidia-drivers-question-for-13-04