# Drivers for HP Pavilion dv7-3165dx

Tags: drivers, hp

Hello I am installing ubuntu on my HP Pavilion dv7-3165dx laptop and was curious if there were drivers compatible with my laptop i did some searching and came up with nothing...the biggest things for me are the integrated webcam and wireless adapter drivers, as i am currently deployed in afghanistan and i have a baby on the way back home so i very much need to talk to my lovely wife. I just did the install and my graphics driver seems to be fine the only other problem i am having is with my wireless adapter it doesn't work so i assume ill need some kind of driver for it, after that i should be set to update and download drivers as needed from there. It looks like im running a Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter. Sorry if my question was kind of vague, and thanks for any help

Thanks Everyone
Jake

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia drivers (graphics) are working for 13.04.
You will find what you need [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285074/is-it-safe-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-13-04)

Comment: I still need the wifi driver, it is still not working. thank you